# Django - How to use Pagination with filter function?

Tags: html, django, search, pagination

I am trying to use `Pagination` with the `Django Filter` function, But I am getting this error.

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_search/?page=2&search=e
    Cannot use None as a query value
    product = Product.objects.filter(productName__contains=name)
```

**Here is The view.py function**

```
def searchProduct(request):
name = request.POST.get("search", None)
try:
    product = Product.objects.filter(productName__contains=name)
    paginator = Paginator(product, 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page_product = paginator.get_page(page)
    if page_product:
        context = {
            'searchResults': page_product,
            'name': name
        }
        return render(request, "Amazon/searchResult.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "Amazon/searchResult.html", {'message': "No Product Found"})
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse("Page Not Found")
```

**Here is HTML/Jinja code**

```
<nav aria-label="...">
    {% if searchResults.has_other_pages %}
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {% if searchResults.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ searchResults.previous_page.number }}&search={{ name }}" tabindex="-1">
                        Previous</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for i  in searchResults.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if product.number == i %}
                    <li class="page-item active">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}&search={{ name }}">{{ i }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if searchResults.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ searchResults.next_page_number }}&search={{ name }}">Next</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link">Next</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</nav>
```

I have a rough Idea that no value is getting passed in filter function that is why it is showing this error. So, any Idea how can I resolve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply filter your queryset when `name` is provided, eg.

```python
name = request.POST.get('search')
page_number = request.GET.get('page')

products = Product.objects.all()

if name:  # only filter when name provided
    products = products.filter(productName__contains=name)

try:
    page = Paginator(products, 2).get_page(page_number)
except EmptyPage:
    return render(request, "Amazon/searchResult.html", {'message': "No Product Found"})
    
return render(request, "Amazon/searchResult.html", {
    'searchResults': page_product,
    'name': name
})
```